# Convexity of $f(x) = \sum_i x_i^p$ for $x_i \ge 0, p \ge 1$

Tags: analysis, inequality, convex-analysis

Let $x = (x_1,\ldots, x_n)$ be nonnegative real numbers and $p \ge 1$, then the function $f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^p$ is convex, the following proof is wrong, or not?

[image]

I have it from [here](http://press.swu.bg/media/27338/stefan%20stefanov.pdf), but then how to proof it?

Comment: The proof of the convexity is fine. Note that $\alpha_i, \beta_i \ge 0$ and $t\in (0,1)$ so $t^p \le t, (1-t)^p \le (1-t)$. What is your actual question? A minor mistake is that the $<$ should also be a $\le$ (consider $x=y=0$ to see why).

Comment: But as $\sum_{k=1}^{p-1} \binom{p}{k} (t\alpha_i)^t[(1-t)\beta_i]^{p-k} \ge 0$ by omitting this term the sum gets smaller, but here he says it gets strictly greater??? This is correct...?

Comment: Are you kidding? I do not agree that $1 + 2 \le 1$, nor $1 \le 0$ or something similar...

Comment: LOOOOL My bad. Let's forget about that ^^

Comment: :D Might be possible the writer of the paper made a similar mistake ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simpler proof: The function $\phi(t)= t^p$ is differentiable for $p \ge 1$ (and $t \ge 0$), with derivative $\phi'(t)=p t^{p-1}$. The derivative is non decreasing, hence $\phi$ is convex. The sum of convex functions is convex, hence $f(x) = \sum_k \phi(x_k)$ is convex.